# TeXstudio Highlighting Issue with \input

Tags: texstudio, highlighting, syntax-highlighting

I have an auxiliary `.tex` file with commands, packages and the like, which I reference with `\input{...}`. However, TeXstudio doesn't recognise the commands in that auxiliary file.

A MWE can be made in the following way.

- Create a file `main.tex` with the following five lines:

  ```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \input{auxiliary.tex}
  \begin{document}
  \mycommand
  \end{document}
  ```
- Create a file `auxiliary.tex` in the same directory/folder as `main.tex` with one line:

  ```
  \newcommand{\mycommand}{is this highlighted?}
  ```

Make sure TeXstudio is closed. Open it, and open `main.tex`. *For me*, `\mycommand` is not recognised, yet the file compiles correctly.

> [image: unrecognised command highlighting]

If the file `auxiliary.tex` is opened in TeXstudio, then, suddenly, the command is recognised by TeXstudio.

Under `Options / Editor` I have "Automatically load included files" ticked.

> [image: auto load included]

This does say *included*, though, which sounds like it's referencing `\include{...}`. My (potentially incorrect) understanding is that I should be using `\input{...}` in this scenario. Certainly, if I use `\include` in the body, to piece together `.tex` files, (I believe) a new page is started each time.

I'm using `TeXstudio 4.6.3 (git 4.6.3)`, with `Qt Version 6.5.2`, compiled with `Qt 6.5.2 R`, on Windows 10.

Comment: I can't help with texstudio but `\include` should never be used in the preamble, `\input` (or better `\usepackage`, and rename to `something.sty`) will work for latex.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle, for the clarification. I thought it was supposed to be `\input`, but I didn't remember that `\include` should *never* be used in the preamble. Thanks for the reminder! You say it's "better" to rename to `auxilary.sty` and use `\usepackage{auxiliary}`. Can you elaborate as to *why* that is better?

Comment: why does latex have `\usepackage` at all, it's basically just `\input` (plus option handling) but many packages have no options, itjust makes the preamble look nicer and have more structure. Also editors like texstudio can recognise certain packages and have built in support without actually reading the package, you don't want texstudio to parse `siunitx` source code to work out what commands it defines, but you might want your editor to recognise `\usepackage{siunitx}` and load some pre-build configuration.

Comment: prior to 2021  `\include` in the preamble would mess things up with no warning,. Since the 2021-11-15 release it does give a warning, but acts like `\input` so works. (but you still shouldn't use it:-)